# Shortcut to stop screencast capture in xvidcap?

Tags: shortcuts, screen-capture

In xvidcap (screencast capture on Linux), is there a shortcut to stop recording?

It is not convenient to have to switch to xvidcap's window and click on "Stop", as it is recorded too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use methods exported via DBUS to control Xvidcap:

```
$ qdbus net.jarre_de_the.Xvidcap /net/jarre_de_the/Xvidcap net.jarre_de_the.Xvidcap.Start
```

and

```
$ qdbus net.jarre_de_the.Xvidcap /net/jarre_de_the/Xvidcap net.jarre_de_the.Xvidcap.Stop
```

There are some more, but these are what you need.

All you have to do is bind them to a global shortcut. In KDE you can use inbuilt KHotKeys for this.